# Allocation Target of std::aligned_storage (stack or heap?)

Tags: c++, c++11, storage, alignment, tr1

I've been trying to get my head around the TR1 addition known as aligned_storage. Whilst reading the following documents [N2165](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2165.pdf), [N3190](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3190.htm) and [N2140](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2140.pdf) I can't for the life of me see a statement where it clearly describes stack or heap nature of the memory being used.

I've had a look at the implementation provided by msvc2010, boost and gcc they all provide a stack based solution centered around the use of a union.

In short:

- Is the memory type (stack or heap) used by aligned_storage implementation defined or is it always meant to be stack based?
- and, What the is the specific document that defines/determines that?

Note: In MSVC10, the following is the definition of the type of aligned_storage, in this case if the aligned_storage is an auto variable the data(_Val,_Pad) is created on the stack:

```
template<class _Ty, size_t _Len> 
union _Align_type
{   
   // union with size _Len bytes and alignment of _Ty
   _Ty _Val;
   char _Pad[_Len];
};
```

Note: This is **NOT** a trivial question. Please try and understand the question before posting an answer.

Answer (score 13):

`std::aligned_storage<Len, Align>` just declares a member typedef (`type`).

> The member typedef `type` shall be a POD type suitable for use as uninitialized storage for any object whose size is at most `Len` and whose alignment is a divisor of `Align`

(This is from the latest C++0x draft, N3225, 20.7.6.6 Table 53, but the language in the TR1 specification, N1836, is effectively the same except that in C++0x the `Align` template parameter has as its default argument the maximum alignment value.)

`std::aligned_storage` doesn't allocate any memory itself.  You can create an object of type `std::aligned_storage<Len, Align>::type` and reinterpret that object as an object of any type that meets the requirements stated above.

Comment: I'm not sure an answer can get better than this. What would be the point if data was dynamically allocated in `type` ? How could that possibly be of any help regarding alignment ?

Comment: @Zenikoder - just read the quote from the Standard again. And again, if needed. :)   `std::aligned_storage<...>::type` defines a POD type with requested alignment. You can allocate storage for this type on stack or in the heap, it's not relevant.

Comment: @Zenikoder - it's not implementation-defined. It's user-defined. The statement quoted by James explains everything clearly enough.

Comment: @Zenikoder:  You're welcome.  On a more serious note, I suppose don't understand the question.  `aligned_storage` doesn't allocate any memory; it defines a type that **you** can use to allocate a block of memory of sufficient size and alignment to hold certain types of objects.  Just like with any other type, you can use whatever form of allocation you'd like:  if you declare a static `aligned_storage` it will have static storage duration, if you declare it locally it will have automatic storage duration, and if you dynamically allocate it then it will have dynamic storage duration.

Answer (score 0):

You typically don't need to align stuff on the heap since any allocation (`new`/`malloc`) returns memory at an address which is aligned to any type.

Comment: This is not quite true. If you use SIMD instruction, you sometimes need to have data aligned 16 bytes boundaries, while new / malloc does not provide such warranty. For exemple, libc malloc return memory aligned on 8 bytes boundary. See `posix_memalign` functions on Linux or `_aligned_malloc` on Windows.

Comment: I was only able to allocate aligned memory on the heap using std::align, which is not yet in gcc4.8, so I use this implementation: http://code.google.com/p/c-plus/source/browse/src/util.h#57